# Pictures folder appears as a bundle?

Tags: finder, photos.app

I'm troubleshooting a relative's Mac and the Finder sees her "Pictures" folder as a bundle. When I right-click to see the package's content, I can see that the folder seems to have the same structure as an iPhoto Library.

What could have caused this, and how can I turn the Pictures folder back into a regular folder?

<sub>I know this is a little vague. Obviously, the person doesn't know anything about that, never realized that the pictures folder was weird, etc. So I'm kinda left in the dark too.</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure how the Pictures folder came to believe it was an iPhoto bundle. Most of the cleanup was just restoring an older version of the Pictures folder from Time Machine.

To turn the Pictures bundle back into a folder, I took the `SetFile` executable from my Mac (ships with the developer tools) and executed `SetFile -a b Pictures`.

This is important, because Mac OS will prohibit most actions done against basic folders in the user directory structure. You cannot move or delete the Pictures folder (and if you `sudo` your way through it, you will be missing some extended attributes on your new folder), so turning it back to normal was an essential step.